# Git pull not pulling everything

Tags: git

I have a server where there's some config that I don't properly know where i just git pull and it gets what is in a github repo, then restart it in order to deploy.

The thing is, there's a commit which isn't my latest, that isn't really on my server. The files aren't in .gitignore. How do I assure that a pull, pulled a commit?

I really don't know how to fix it, I'm thinking about restarting everything :(

```
14:41][root@someserver] someserver_dir (master)$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   Gemfile
#   modified:   Gemfile.lock
#   modified:   config/assets.yml
#   modified:   config/database.yml
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   randomfiles
```

Comment: More information will make it easier to answer your question. What does `git status` show you? Are you on the right branch locally? For instance, if you're looking at the `master` branch on the server, are you checked out to `master` locally? How about `git log origin/master..master`?

Comment: Is the git repository public? If so, provide a URL.

Comment: not public, git status shows me everything is cool, there's only a branch.

Comment: I've tried commiting the changes again, and magically, when I pull, nothing happens(already up to date).

Comment: Include the output of `git status`.

Comment: Thanks. Will you also include `git config --list`?

Comment: Exclude any sensitive data of course. The point of my asks for additional data are that you need to figure out which question to ask, and more information will help me (or someone) help you ask it.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

If you always want your server version to reflect a commit from your repo, it's probably better to use `git reset` instead of `git pull` - that way you never invoke merge functionality, but instead set all of the files to exactly what they are in the commit you reset to. For example:

```
git fetch origin master
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: I always forget this command, so I keep coming back to this thread. Just wanted to add that changing 'master' to any other branch name works as well, if you want to fetch everything from a specific branch.

Comment: you might as well reset to a specific branch, so git reset --hard origin/master also works, so as any branch you specify. (quite funny to see myself asking this question 5 years ago, I remember I was managing some remote server which used git to deploy and ended up in a bad state.. haha)

Comment: After this files are restored as in origin, but i got this "fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'FETCH_HEAD'." Anything I have to do?

Comment: Saved my day!!! Been struggling with this for quite a while, couldn't figure out why i was not pulling latest changes in a brand new branch, from origin master.

Comment: Awesome it worked. I tried `git fetch origin <branchname>` followed by `git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD`. This branch was visible on github.com but not in my local, even after trying `git pull` many times.

Comment: ```git fetch origin main``` now

Answer (score 14):

You can use `git pull origin branch_name`.

Ex: If I have a production branch on GitHub, then I will write `git pull origin production` which will give me all the latest commits.

Only doing `git pull` sometimes does not give you the latest commits of production branch even though you are working on that branch and committing it.

Behind the scenes working

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_default_behaviour

[Explanation and Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797183/differences-between-git-pull-commands-when-pulling-from-origin)

Comment: This worked for me. Would have been nice to give a better explanation as to why.

Comment: I have added the documentation as well as links to other peoples answers for better understanding. @VendettaV - Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 4):

Try cleaning-up your local repository with and then run git pull:

```
$ git gc --prune=now
$ git remote prune origin
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if your branch is tracking the right latest commit. Check it using `git branch -avv`

If it really does not track the right commit, hard reset the FETCH_HEAD using `git reset --hard [commit hash]`

Answer (score -1):

```
git fetch origin master
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

From the first comment.