# Git pull not working properly?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-clone

My repository structure is like this:

```
Main folder
|-- A
|    |-- some 
|    +-- files
|
+-- B
    |-- some
    |-- more
    +-- files
```

But when I pull it only `A` folder is there.

Comment: Is B  a submodule? (do you have a .gitmodules file in your Mainfolder?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git pull not pulling everything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688867/git-pull-not-pulling-everything)

Comment: @VonC No there is no .gitmoduoles file in main directory. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
git clone --recursive
```

It will download any [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) listed in `.gitmodules`.

Comment: @Riturajratan I've updated my answer with a possible solution (a reset) without Git submodules.