# GIT won't pull latest changes from remote

Tags: git, bitbucket

Somehow my local branch is stuck 8 months behind my remote branch.

When I do `git pull origin [my branch name]` it says `Already up to date`.

I tried `git fetch origin [my branch name]` then `git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD` ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688867/git-pull-not-pulling-everything)) but my local copy is still pointing to the super old commit.

I've also tried resetting to the specific by using `git checkout 1d5d525`  ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)) but it says: `error: pathspec '1d5d525' did not match any file(s) known to git.` but that commit is 100% in the remote branch because I can see it in BitBucket.

The only thing I can think of that I've done any differently was that yesterday I worked on a different machine (my OSX laptop, rather than my Win10 desktop) but that doesn't explain why it's 8 months behind.

If any gurus could give me some guidance, that would be awesome.

NOTE: I can commit more changes from my laptop and they show up on my branch in BitBucket, but still no luck.

NOTE: I'm the only person that works on this branch in case that info is important.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the output for `git branch -vv` and `git remote - v` as requested.

```
$ git branch -vv
ImageEdit 39b733c Image editing tweaks
Widgets   cce09e8 Merge Globals + Widgets to use the same functionality / DB table
* john      11798f3 [origin/john] Finished PDF Header. Waiting for feedback...
master    cce09e8 Merge Globals + Widgets to use the same functionality / DB table

$ git remote - v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:johnt/website.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:johnt/website.git (push)
```

NOTE: I'll point out that the master branch also seems to be way behind the remote based on the above commit message.

EDIT 2:

Here is the output for `git branch -a -vv`

```
$ git branch -a -vv
ImageEdit                39b733c Image editing tweaks
Widgets                  cce09e8 Merge Globals + Widgets to use the same functionality / DB table
* john                   11798f3 [origin/john] Finished PDF Header. Waaiting for feedback...
master                   cce09e8 Merge Globals + Widgets to use the same functionality / DB table
remotes/origin/ImageEdit 39b733c Image editing tweaks
remotes/origin/Widgets   cce09e8 Merge Globals + Widgets to use the same functionality / DB table
remotes/origin/glenn     0548f0d Changed Create a Lifeshare Page to Create a Lifeshare
remotes/origin/john      11798f3 Finished PDF Header. Waiting for feedback...
remotes/origin/master    cce09e8 Merge Globals + Widgets to use the same functionality / DB table
```

Comment: Could we see the output from `git branch -vv`. And while you are at it `git remote -v`

Comment: @AnimiVulpis I've updated my original post.

Comment: Sry, but could you change the command from `git branch -vv` to `git branch -a -vv`. This way we could see if your local copies of the remote branches are at least up to date (Because `-a` will show you local as well as remote branches).

Comment: @AnimiVulpis Info added as requested. Thanks a lot for taking the time to look into this for me.

Comment: You did not do a `git push --force` I suppose? It seems like the remote and your local branches are up-to-date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct etiquette but I was able to resolve myself even though @VonC and @AnimiVulpis we helping out.

Using `git branch -a -vv` showed that both local and remote branches were pointing to the same commit, but that commit was wrong (that commit was from 8 months ago).

I cloned the repository into a new folder, logged into Bitbucket to get the latest commit hash and used `git reset --hard [commit hash]` to point the HEAD to the correct commit.

Now everything seems to be working fine (although in a different directory lol). I'm not sure how the remote branch ended up pointing to that commit, but glad the issue is resolved.

Thanks to both @VonC and @AnimiVulpis for taking time to help.

Comment: A fetch would have been enough.

Comment: @VonC I did ```git fetch --all``` but that still made it point to the wrong commit. I guess I should have done ```git reset --hard [commit hash]``` to save the trouble of doing the clone, but from memory, it displayed an error when trying to do that. Oh well, it seems the issue is resolved.

Comment: Yes, that was my answer: fetch + reset

Answer (score 1):

From your output, the local branches and remote tracking branches refer to the same commits, and are therefore up-to-date.

Try a `git fetch` to confirm: it will update the remote tracking branches for all branches.
Then a `git branch -avv` will show if there is any difference.

And a `git branch -f mybranch origin/mybranch` (or `git checkout -B mybranch origin/mybranch`) would be enough to reset it.